# limit of an integral and estimate the limit of integrand

Tags: analysis

I have $$\lim \limits_{k\rightarrow 0}\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}f_{k}(x)g(x)\rightarrow 0.$$ Could you please tell me if it is possible to show $$\lim \limits_{k\rightarrow 0}f_{k}(x)\rightarrow 0$$ when $g(x)$ is an infinitely continuous function?

Comment: what if $g$ has zero integral and $f_k = \rm Id_{\mathbb R}$ for any k ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, generally. This is related to the notion of [weak convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_%28Hilbert_space%29); here's a simple counterexample. Suppose we work in $[0,2 \pi]$, and $f_k(x) = \sin (k x)$. Then $\int_0^{2 \pi} g f_k dy \rightarrow 0$ for any smooth $g$ by the Riemann Lebesgue lemma, whereas $f_k$ does not converge at (most) points of $[0,2 \pi)$.

The point is that a statement of the form "$\int f_k g dy \rightarrow 0$" is much weaker/different than the pointwise or almost sure convergence of $f_k \rightarrow 0$. In general these notions are completely different.

Comment: I think Damien L's counterexample is a really simple counterexample, no? You can even take $g=0$ and $f_k=1$.

Comment: @julien I realize upon re-reading the question that the hypothesis was 'for some $g$' and not 'for all $g$'; on the other hand it's interesting to note that even if you assume this for a large class of functions, the result is still false.